# IIS rewrite rule not triggered when file-name plus extension is in the url

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I am struggling getting an IIS rewrite rule working.

The old urls look like:
*https://wwww.testserver.com/package.aspx?TrackingNumber=number*

The new web app is expecting the urls in this format:
*https://wwww.testserver.com/package/number*

Currently I have the following rule setup, which is not working.

`<rule name="Rewrite to new Package site" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^package\.aspx\?TrackingNumber=([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.testserver.com/package/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
    </rule>`

The interesting part is, if I remove **package.aspx\?** from the rule, urls like these *https://wwww.testserver.com/oldwebsite/TrackingNumber=number* are getting matched.

In my test calls I replaced **package.aspx** with **package.html** and these urls are not getting matched as well. It looks like IIS ignores urls with filenames in the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use below url rewrite rule to redirect  https://wwww.testserver.com/package.aspx?TrackingNumber=number to https://wwww.testserver.com/package/number:

```
<rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="package(.aspx)" />
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="TrackingNumber=(.*)" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://localhost:2568/package/{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
```

[image]

**Note: You could modify hostname as per your requirement.**

Regards,
Jalpa